# Require Capability to View Woocommerce Product

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, plugins

I am using Woocommerce and I have products in a category called B2B whose single_product.php is only to be shown to people with the capability read_b2b.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop'); ?>
<?php if (is_product_category('b2b')) && if current_user_can('read_b2b') { ?>
  //*** In this case show the PRODUCT with the LOOP ***
       <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
       <?php woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>
       <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
<?php } else { 
  //*** show error message ***
  echo '<p>You have to be a registered b2b user to see this product</p>';
?>
```

Can you help me get this hack to work for single-product.php?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your problem is here:

```
if (is_product_category('b2b'))
```

Taking a look at the [Woocommerce Documention for Conditional Tags](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/theming/conditional-tags/) `is_product_category()` will return `true` on product category archives.  Therefore, it will **never** be true on the single product page.

What I think you need instead is [`has_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) which checks a post for a particular term.  Therefore I would suggest you change your conditional to:

```
<?php if (has_term('b2b', 'product_cat')) && if current_user_can('read_b2b') { ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [WooCommerce documentation](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/), I'd think you may want to use the hook/filter woocommerce_before_main_content.